# Non-english spell check dictionaries for Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, customization, dictionary

I've spent a fair amount of time bending Mathematica for taking notes and I've been very happy with it, the only missing piece it seems is a nice spell check dictionary for Polish (my mother language).

If anyone could point me to the right resources; where to download or how to convert an existing dictionary to one compatible with Mathematica I'd be very grateful.

--- Update ---

Alright, so I've recognized that the spelling dictionary probably sits in `Mathematica/Contents/SystemFiles/SpellingDictionaries/English/Mathematica.rws` and I've found some clues that it might be an aspell dictionary, so I've downloaded an aspell polish dictionary from http://sjp.pl/slownik/en/, builded it to .rws (here's a [zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2156550/English.zip)) and then tried to replace the default English dictionary (because putting dictionaries side by side in `/SpellingDictionaries` didn't work either) and when I've tried to spell-check a document the box reported a problem with Mathematica.rws which probably is CodeSigned and therefore cannot be easily replaced...

--- Update 2 ---

The first 32 bytes look exactly the same so the format should (?) be correct.

Well, I guess we may be left stuck just one last step to a working solution.

Comment: Have you seen [DictionaryLookup](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DictionaryLookup.html)?

Comment: Have you seen [How to | Spell Check a Notebook](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SpellCheckANotebook.html)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Are you on windows? On Mac all I found is Mathematica/Contents/SystemFiles/SpellingDictionaries/English with a bunch of files in a weird format http://i.imgur.com/noyYfN0.png

Comment: @Lou yes, I saw those. That doesn't help here unluckily.

Comment: I found /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Dictionaries/English/dictionary.txt --I guess it's not the spelling dictionary.  Missed that other directory.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to swap it with another dictionary but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: @ilian perhaps somebody knows how to make a cross-platform dict with aspell?

Comment: While I can't comment on features under development, the spell checking engine and dictionary format may change altogether, so that it would be much easier to add a dictionary for your language (if not already included).

Comment: @ilian let me just note that modifying an LGPL library such as `aspell` and then linking it into *Mathematica* obliges WRI to make available (strictly, as part of the *Mathematica* distribution) the source code for the modified library. So far as I can tell, this has not been done, but should be. Thus, it ought to be possible (if a user is sufficiently motivated) to generate a compatible dictionary file.

Comment: @OleksandrR Good point, and I am not a lawyer, so may be hopelessly confused, but I think that since it is a dynamic library, users can swap in their own version compiled from the official aspell sources (plus appropriate dictionary), and that satisfies the LGPL requirements.

Comment: @ilian section 6 (a) of LGPL 2.1 and section 4 (d) (0) of LGPL 3 make clear that the source for the modified library must be provided if code is distributed that links to it. This is so that the modification remains under the LGPL rather than becoming proprietary--LGPL is still a copyleft licence; it just doesn't have the "viral" character of GPL. The interoperability requirement is separate and satisfied in part by having the library dynamically linked, but documentation must be provided about the interface to facilitate replacement. This can be achieved by supplying the source code.

Comment: @ilian the key distinction is as to what or is not is a derivative work. The modified library is clearly a derivative of the original and so must be made available under the terms of the (L)GPL. Code that links to it (rather than incorporating it) is not considered a *derivative* work under the LGPL but merely a *combined* work. This is in contrast to the GPL, where linking (understood in the broadest possible sense) is sufficient to produce a derivative work. These terms are to be understood in the context of copyright since GPL/LGPL rely on copyright law for their applicability.

Comment: @OleksandrR Thank you for explaining, I am not sure what the answer is, but I will let the appropriate people know. It is possible my speculation about what was modified was simply wrong.

Comment: So, Mathematica 10.3.1 brought some language changes "Refined support for international language and translation, including Spanish spell checking and Chinese search" does it help us anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is solved with version 11 of Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

In 10.4 there are new language functions like `DictionaryWordQ` and `SpellingCorrectionList`:

```
DictionaryWordQ["delfin", Language -> Interpreter["Language"]["Polish"]]
(*True*)    

SpellingCorrectionList["telewozja", Language -> Interpreter["Language"]["Polish"]]
(*{"telewizja"}*)
```

Comment: Great find! Now how can one **easily** spell check a notebook?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dictionaryLanguage = "Polish";

Unprotect[DictionaryLookup];

DictionaryLookup[pat : Except[_List], x___] /; ! TrueQ[$dicLang] && 
       ValueQ[$dictionaryLanguage] := 
 Block[{$dicLang = True}, 
      DictionaryLookup[{$dictionaryLanguage, pat}, x]]

DownValues[DictionaryLookup] = 
  RotateRight@DownValues[DictionaryLookup];

Protect[DictionaryLookup];
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how this helps?