# Non-English spell checking dictionaries in Mathematica: Where to get them?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, dictionary

I simply want to be able to spell check my (german) notebooks.

There was a question similar to this but with no answer:

[Non-english spell check dictionaries for Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94365/non-english-spell-check-dictionaries-for-mathematica)

You can find this Wolfram page:

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4715/

"Available dictionaries include Brazilian Portuguese, ..."

But no further infos or link where to get them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried contacting WRI support? No new, but if this is indeed the same question, then it might be closed as duplicate...

Comment: Yes I wrote an email to the German distributor about a week ago - no answer yet.

Comment: Additionally sending a message to WRI support (not the distributer) might be useful, too.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? From version 11 on there is support for German (in the preferences).

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this one (it apparently worked for me):
[image: Selecting spell check language by Global Preferences DefaultNaturalLanguage]

Documentation tells about it:
**DefaultNaturalLanguage**
is an option for character selections that specifies the language used when checking the spelling of a word in a human natural language selection. ... The language can also be specified explicitly as a string, for example, by setting DefaultNaturalLanguage to "English", "French", or "German".